# Call another form functions from the first form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I hope the title is clear enough. Let me explain : I am doing a c# Winform App. When I start the app I have my **Form 1** which starts, and I have other forms I can open from it by clicking buttons.

The problem is, I have functions in those Forms (**Form 2, Form 3, Form 4..**) I want to start from the **Form 1** .

Currently here's my code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

     // First Event, when I click in the toolstrip menu, I open the Form2 ("Ligne3")
    private void ligne3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Ligne3 = new Ligne3();
        Ligne3.Show();
    }
```

Then, I have components in the Form2 (textboxs, buttons, functions etc)

```
public partial class Ligne3 : Form
{

    public Ligne3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Ligne3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code
    }
    }

    //Function I want to call from the Form1
    public void send_email()
    {
     //Some code
    }
```

How can I start my " send_email() " function from the Form1 (for example during Load Event) ?

Comment: var ligne3 = new Ligne3(); ligne3.send_email() ?

Comment: @mybirthname this solution does not takes the parameters which are set for the mail settings for example in the Form2.. It throws an error during debug

Comment: So preset this settings or add them as dependencies in the method signature.

Comment: @mybirthname Yes, but I have settings which come from the App.config file, it is not only variables

Comment: Change the signature of the method or take the setting from app config in the method

Comment: Your form should not be sending an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the values of `Form2` or any other objects/variables to Linge3 object before calling show. Values which are needed in `send_email()` to be assigned before calling `send_email()`. Something like below.

```
private void ligne3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ligne3 = new Ligne3();
        //define variables/properties in Ligne3 for all values to be passed
        //then assign them with corresponding values
        ligne3.Value1 = objForm2.Value1; 
        ligne3.Value2 = objForm2.Value2; 
        ligne3.Value3 = objForm2.textBox1.Text;
        ligne3.Value3 = objForm2.checkBox1.Value;
        //and so on
        ligne3.send_email();
        ligne3.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how to "make know" the existence of textboxs, and other visual components of  the Form2(Ligne 3) to Form1 ? I have assigned all the variables but Form1 does not recognize the textboxs from the Form 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are clicking a buttons on Form1, to start and open forms 2,3,4 etc, and in those `btn_click` handlers you are creating a `new` form2, 3,3,4. Then you will have a reference to each form and and can therefore just call the respective public method on the instance just created. eg

```
public class Form1
{
    private Form2 subForm2;

   private void OpenForm2_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
   {
       subForm2 = new Form2();
       subForm2.Show()
   }

   private void sendEmailBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        subForm2.Send_email();
   }
}
```

This are many things wrong with the above from a design point of view but i'm just using it to present the idea.
If you are creating the instance of Form2,3,4 etc outside of Form1's instantiation, then you would need some form of Constructor or property injection to provide the instance references.